# Unable to mount folder with Vagrant & Vagrant box laravel/homestead on vagrant up

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I am on macOS and have installed virtualbox, vagrant & laravel homestead following the setup at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead.

My versions are:

- macOS 10.14.4
- vagrant 2.2.4
- vagrant box : laravel/homestead 7.2.1
- virtualbox 5.2.28r130011

When I run `vagrant up` I get the error:

```
homestead-7: Unable to mount one of your folders. Please check your folders in Homestead.yaml
```

My Homestead.yaml file is

```
folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: firstproject.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
```

When I go onto the virtual machine using `vagrant ssh` I can see that the files from my local have been synced on the virtual box to:

`/vagrant/code`

and not to

`/home/vagrant/code`

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by adding the `code` folder to the wrong place in the file system.

Folder was added to `~/Homestead/code` instead of `~/code` as per the `Homestead.yaml` file

```
folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

### Why did it sync to `/vagrant` on the VM?

from 
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/index.html

"By default, Vagrant will share your project directory (the directory with the Vagrantfile) to /vagrant."